# Assign a value to the most common characteristics by subgroup

Tags: r, function, loops, assign

If a individual have no type of housing (0 in each columns: Type1, Type2, Type3, Type4), I would like to assign to him the most common Type of housing in his municipality.
I tried this code but it did not work.

```
mostCommon <- function(df,columnsNames){
  # INPUTS : df le dataframe, columnsNames une liste de str des colonnes à checker. CE SONT DES DUMMIES !
  # OUTPUT : le nom de la colonne qui contient le + de fois la modalité 1.
  
  liste = c("Type1", "Type2", "Type3","Type4") # Liste qui va contenir ttes les modalités
  
  for (i in 1:length(columnsNames)){
    liste[i] = sum(df[columnsNames[i]])
  } # Ajouter la somme des modalités
  
  return(columnsNames[which(liste == max(liste))])
}


abc <- data_object%>%
  group_by(municipality) %>% mostCommon(data_object, c("Type1", "Type2", "Type3","Type4")) %>% Type(i)[0]<-1
```

Data looks like:
[data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PIbBB.png)

Comment: Please don't post your data as an image: it makes it difficult to use it to test our code.  Use `dput()` instead and post the output to your question.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Let's use the following input data (e.g. as csv) for testing.

```
community;type1;type2;type3;type4
A;0;0;1;0
B;0;0;0;1
A;0;0;1;0
A;0;1;0;0
B;1;0;0;1
```

... and put it in a data.frame called datahouse. Now

```
tmp <- aggregate(datahouse[,2:5],list(comm=datahouse$community),sum)
```

sums up for each housing type the number of housings of this type in every community. For the above example:

```
  comm type1 type2 type3 type4
1    A     0     1     2     0
2    B     1     0     0     2
```

Given a community, we can find out from this which housing type is the most common. E.g.

```
which.max(tmp[tmp$comm=="A",][2:5])
```

yields that "Housing Type 3" is the most common in "Community A".

Note that the maximum is, in general, not unique, i.e. there might be housing types which are equally common.

Answer (score 0):

```
df <-data_object


# helper df
maketype.f <- function( df ){
  df_helper <- df %>% group_by(municipality) %>%
    # create some helping columns for logic
    # T# will be the sums of each Type by the grouping
    # HelperCheck will decide if all is blank
    mutate( T1 = sum(Type1),
            T2 = sum(Type2),
            T3 = sum(Type3),
            T4 = sum(Type4),
            HelperCheck = (Type1 + Type2 + Type3 + Type4)==0,
            helpermax = max(T1,T2,T3,T4),
            T1 = as.numeric(T1 == helpermax),
            T2 = as.numeric(T2 == helpermax),
            T3 = as.numeric(T3 == helpermax),
            T4 = as.numeric(T4 == helpermax),
            sumHelp = T1 + T2 + T3 + T4)
  for( row_i in seq_along(df_helper$municipality) ){
    if( !df_helper$HelperCheck[row_i] ){
      next
    }
    randomwinner <- sample(c(1,rep(0,df_helper$sumHelp[row_i]-1) ), replace = F)
    for( winner in seq_along(randomwinner) ){
      if( df_helper$T1[row_i] == 1 ){
        df_helper$Type1[row_i] <- randomwinner[winner]
        df_helper$T1[row_i] <- 0
        next
      }
      if( df_helper$T2[row_i] == 1 ){
        df_helper$Type2[row_i] <- randomwinner[winner]
        df_helper$T2[row_i] <- 0
        next
      }
      if( df_helper$T3[row_i] == 1 ){
        df_helper$Type3[row_i] <- randomwinner[winner]
        df_helper$T3[row_i] <- 0
        next
      }
      if( df_helper$T4[row_i] == 1 ){
        df_helper$Type4[row_i] <- randomwinner[winner]
        df_helper$T4[row_i] <- 0
        next
      }
    }
  }
  ret_df <- df_helper %>% select(-T1,-T2,-T3,-T4,-HelperCheck,-helpermax,-sumHelp)
  return(ret_df)
}
df<-maketype.f(df)
```